# Java HashMap get() method not returning element

Tags: java, android, hashmap

Using expressions in the NetBeans debugger I have figured that a value should definitely be returned from a HashMap (backoffMap), but I only get null. The key in the HashMap does not have a null value according to NetBeans. The screenshots show the insanity I'm seeing. What's going on?

[image]

[image]

It should be noted that this is running on Android API level 16. I'm not sure but the behaviour of Dalvik and the Android Java libraries might be different, and be causing this issue.

Comment: What about `backoffMap.keySet().toArray()[82].equals(b)`? Can you produce a short but complete program demonstrating this? (That would make it a lot easier to help you.)

Comment: You probably modified the key after it was put in the HashMap. Since it doesn't have the same hashCode than it had when put in the map, it's still in the keySet, but get() doesn't find it in the bucket where it should be according to its new hashCode.

Comment: The screenshot demonstrates the hashcodes are the same, unless I'm blind. The key class is a custom class of type PeerAddress, implementing it's own equals() and hashCode(). @JonSkeet: I will do the reverse equals() when I can replicate the conditions once again (not easy), as my program just exited/disconnected suddenly.

Thanks.

Comment: The suspected problem is not that b and the key have a different hahsCode. The suspected problem is that you put the key in the map with a hashCode A, then modified the key (hashCode becomes B). Now when you look for the key in the map, it looks for it in bucket B, but it is still in bucket A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you modify the object after it was inserted into the HashMap? If so, then the hashcode on the object you are searching for will be different from what it was when it was inserted into the map. This will prevent you from finding the object in the map.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. You and JB Nizet get credit for this obvious answer that I did not even think about.